# Passing limit through derivative!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

In the book "General topology" of Lipschutz, exercise 26 at page 222 says that: if $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real value differentiable funtions on $[a, b]$ which converge uniformly to $g$ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=  \frac{d}{dx}\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x).$$ 
But I find that the sequence $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx), \ \ x\in [0, 1]$$ satisfying $f_n$ converge uniformly to $g(x)\equiv 0$ but $\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=-\sin(nx)$ diverges as $n \to \infty$. This is a contradiction!

What explanations could you give me to know this?

Comment: I see two options. There's an error in the book, or you misread it. Neither is unbelievable, but the first seems more likely here.

Comment: This statement is definitely false. The weakest result of this kind I know of requires uniform convergence of **derivatives** and pointwise convergence of sequence in at least one point.

Comment: How can a sequence of bounded function diverge?

Comment: In this case, $g(x)$ is a constant function and $\frac{d}{dx}g=0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)$ does not converges to $g'=0$.

Comment: @alex $1$, $-1$, $1$, $\cdots$.

Comment: Well, $-\sin(nx)$ does not take only values $1$ and $-1$. Furthermore, you mean that the sequence does not converge, which doesn't imply that it diverges. At least according to what I intend for divergence, namely that it tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @alex: Mathematicians use "diverge" as a synonym for "does not converge". Your criteria would be expressed "diverges to $+\infty$" or "diverges to $-\infty$". :)

Comment: Well, some mathematicians, not mathematicians in general, surely not the ones I know, including me, who belong to the club. Anyway we agree that the statement is not true.

Comment: Thus, we can stop to discus this problem now! Thanks for all comments!