# Passing a derivative through a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

After searching around on the net and on [SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695121/passing-limit-through-derivative) I have not found a satisfactory answer.

Let $f_n: D \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of functions. What assumptions, aside from $f$ being differentiable, do we need to make in order to have $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{dx}}\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\mathrm d f_n(x)}{\mathrm{dx}} .$$

I vaguely recall reading over some theorem that proved the statement but I can not find it anymore. Could someone perhaps, cite a reference to a relevant theorem?

I expect using convergence arguments in the proof, is there also some need for topology in some sense?

> **Note**. I want to prove the statement by myself, so I patiently ask not to give an answer of any kind. Suggestions are welcome for now.

Comment: $x$ must me uniformly continuous

Comment: Your tag "limit-theorems" doesn't fit, consider eliminating it.

Answer (score 3):

From Bartle and Sherbert, *Introduction to Real Analysis*, 3rd ed.:

> **8.2.3** Theorem $\quad{}$ Let $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval and let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions on $J$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that there exists $x_0 \in J$ such that $\left(f_{n}\left(x_0\right)\right)$ converges, and that the sequence $\left(f^{\prime}_{n}\right)$ exists on $J$ and converges uniformly on $J$ to a function $g$. Then the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $J$ to a function $f$ that has a derivative at every point of $J$ and $f' = g$.

Answer (score 3):

[It suffices to assume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) that the right-hand limit of functions
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{df_n(x)}{dx}
$$
converges uniformly in $x$ (as opposed to simply pointwise).